# How do I find values that are missing specific characters with regex

Tags: sql, regex

I am new to using regex and I am having hard time creating a regex to extract all the values with the following data.

(city name secondname)
or
(ci.Name)

normally it should be:
(city „name secondname“) - without the () 
or
(ci.„name“)

I want to find out all that are missing the („“), so I can add them.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I am sorry, should have given this before.

So, I have data of street names and some of them are missing quotation marks and I want to find them so I add them. below is the values I found and how they should be looking normally. 

ул. Милениум - Should be ул.„Милениум“                                                     
улица Жул Леви - Should be улица „Жул Леви"

Answer (score 0):

This may provide what you are looking for

```
select cityname
from YourTableName
where REGEXP_LIKE(cityname,'[' ||unistr('\201C')|| ']')
```

Of course, you need to use actual table and column names from your schema.

This returns rows where cityname has “ (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK). We need to use its Unicode value, which is 201C. You can find Unicode values here: http://inamidst.com/stuff/unidata
Specifically, see the "General Punctuation" section.

This query returns rows where cityname does not have “

```
select cityname
from YourTableName
where NOT REGEXP_LIKE(cityname,'[' ||unistr('\201C')|| ']')
```

Comment: This is working, Thank you. I was just wondering if it could be done without unistr? Since I am using SQL and I had a little problem changing it aroung

Comment: Try this:  select cityname
from YourTableName
where REGEXP_LIKE(cityname, NCHR(8220))